# how to use python visual debugger in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Does anyone knows a visual debugger that can be used with google colab. I tried PixieDebugger, however, its not working for me, I can install it and import it but when I use it in Colab(%%pixie_debugger) it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2):

How visual do you want - have you tried the `%debug` magic?

Enter this into a cell and run it.

```
%debug
x = 1
y = 2
z = x * y
print(z)
```

You should see a prompt like this

```
ipdb>
```

It's a debugger so there are commands to examine variables and move forward and so on.

Type `r` to exit.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, however, I was looking for a visual debugger that is easy to use instead of using ipdb and debug for example "PixieDebugger".

Comment: This is the output.

ERROR:root:No traceback has been produced, nothing to debug.

2

Comment: Colab seems to have changed - `%pdb on` seems to work however, I will update the answer.